# Property 'style' does not exist on type 'ChildNode' Type Script

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom

i have a code like bellow. It works great, but TypeScript show me:
Property 'style' does not exist on type 'ChildNode' Type Script. This error

```
  const allCoins = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li')))
  const xs = !useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('xs'))
  const md = !useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'))

  allCoins.map((coins) => {
    if (coins.offsetHeight >= 53 && xs && !md) {
      allCoins.map((coin) => {
        coin.childNodes[0].childNodes[2].style.flex = '1 0 100%'
        coin.childNodes[0].childNodes[2].style.marginLeft = '-3px'
      })
    } else {
      allCoins.map((coin) => {
        coin.childNodes[0].childNodes[2].style.flex = 'unset' 
        coin.childNodes[0].childNodes[2].style.marginLeft = '0'
      })
    }
  })
```

I tried every solution i saw on Stack and Fit, but no one works for me.

Comment: Are there any childNodes inside childNodes? could you please provide more information? like the structure of coin object

Comment: @SimaAmini
Yes. Structure looks like this: 
ul -> li -> div -> div

Comment: Ok i finally found solution (coin.childNodes[0].childNodes[2] as HTMLElement) works for me

Comment: You should post a complete code example, post your answer, and accept your own answer so this is a complete reference point for future readers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution, works perfect for me :)

```
  const allCoins: HTMLElement[] = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'))
  const xs = !useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('xs'))
  const md = !useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'))

  allCoins.map((coins) => {
    if (coins.offsetHeight >= 53 && xs && !md) {
      allCoins.map((coin) => {
        (coin.childNodes[0].childNodes[2] as HTMLElement).style.flex = '1 0 100%';
        (coin.childNodes[0].childNodes[2] as HTMLElement).style.marginLeft = '-3px';
      })
    } else {
      allCoins.map((coin) => {
        (coin.childNodes[0].childNodes[2] as HTMLElement).style.flex = 'unset';
        (coin.childNodes[0].childNodes[2] as HTMLElement).style.marginLeft = '0';
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).